# ValueError : Random forest classification by scikit learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am solving a classification problem using Random Forests. I transformed a sentence to num by BOW. And I put a label into it, and built a tree.

```
data_train = [[1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0]]

label_train = [1,2]

estimator = RandomForestClassifier()

estimator.fit_transform(data_train, label_train)
```

and I prepared a test_data which was a sentence to try prediction. But it didn't work.

```
test_data = [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]

label_predict = estimator.predict_proba(test_data)


ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 2 and input n_features is 12
```

I know it says the number of element doesn't match. But the number of words in the sentence is different, it must be different, I think. How should I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example your train data has two features/dimensions/columns (the number of rows is irrelevant for this issue):

```
[[1.0, 1.0], 
 [2.0, 2.0]]
```

and you have a label for each of the rows/samples.

```
[1,
 2]
```

Your test data has to look similar, i.e, it must have the same number of features/dimension/columns. For example this would be ok:

```
[[1.0, 1.0],
 [1.0, 1.0], 
 [1.0, 1.0],
 [1.0, 1.0], 
 [1.0, 1.0],
 [1.0, 1.0]]
```

You can have different number of rows but the number of columns has to be the same. In this case you have 2 columns and 6 rows, so you will get 6 labels as a result of `predict_proba`.

Comment: Thanks.So, I have to make test_data two colums without changing the meaning of the data.(or change the train_data)

Comment: Yes, most probably each column represents something(the same) in both your train and your test data.